# What is a packed transaction?

Tags: cleos, eosjs, keosd

This could be a noob question. While going through the community, I have seen some questions regarding `packed transaction`. Can anyone explain what is a `packed transaction`?

Comment: it's the current transaction packed in binary form to be accessible in the transaction itself

Comment: So, is that the output of 'abi_json_to_bin' RPC API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A packed transaction is one where the transaction structure is converted from the JSON format into a packed binary format.  In the C++ code in EOS, this is done using Boost.  The `abi_json_to_bin` method is used to pack smart contract method arguments into a packed format.  Packing a transaction uses a similar process.